# How to retrieve ALL data from database by selecting ALL in dropdown list

Tags: php

I have a list of branches in dropdownlist .while selecting a particular branch i am able to retrieve data from mysql database for that branch.If i select ALL in dropdownlist the data for all the branches should be retrieved from mysql database.Here i am facing problem.

any help by using php is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: if($_POST['dropdown_selection'] == all) { SELECT * FROM database }

Comment: can you show your code ? btw Andrew's comment is way to go